# Application in c# without dot net framework

Tags: c#

I am building an application using windows forms c# and I want to install it on the client machine. The client does not have dot net framework installed in his system. Can anyone tell me if there is any tool to convert the program to Executable so that the application runs without installing dot net framework?

Comment: There is no such tool. If you program requires .NET Framework, you should include it into your installer

Comment: c# means with .net. W/o .net use c++ & mfc